# How do I use Jinja2 filter on a block with argumets

Tags: python, jinja2

I am trying to use `jinja2` templates. I have custom filter called `highlight`, that takes string and language name and passes them to `pyhments` for code highlightning. I am trying to use it like this:

```
{% filter highlight("python") %}
import sys

def main():
    pass
{% endfilter %}
```

But I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get_tokens'
```

Then I tried this:

```
{% filter highlight "python" %}
```

It does not work either.

There might be a trick via [set block filtering](https://github.com/pallets/jinja/compare/master...ThiefMaster:set-block-filters) and then pasting it back via `{{ ... }}`, but this technique is not merged in master source code yet, and seems too hacky for me.

So, is that even possible currently, or I am just doing it wrong?

**EDIT**: Here is filter:

```
@jinja2.contextfilter
def highlight(context, code, lang):
    print("HIGHLIGHT")
    print(code)
    return jinja2.Markup(pygments.highlight(code, lexer=lang, formatter='html'))
```

Comment: Can you show the definition for your custom `highlight` filter?

Comment: @hjpotter92 Added to the post.

Comment: Which line does it show the error in?

Comment: @hjpotter92 deep inside `jinja2` (last trace entry is in lexer, line 374), or if you are asking about the source template, in the first line itself (`{% filter ...`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am an idiot, that was `pygments` error. By some mistake, I didn't see that last entry in stacktrace was from there.

You should use:

```
pygments.highlight(
    code, 
    lexer=pygments.lexers.get_lexer_by_name(lang), 
    formatter=pygments.formatters.get_formatter_by_name('html')
)
```

instead of:

```
pygments.highlight(code, lexer=lang, formatter='html')
```